# can someone explain why this returns the "else" value and not the "then" value?

Tags: java, equals

the java subSequence is clearly true but only returns the false value. why?
trying to see if a sequence is equal to a subsequence of a bigger string

```
package testifthen;


public class TestIfThen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
String result = "01900287491234567489";
String result1 = "90028749";


if (result.subSequence(2, 10) == result1) {
        System.out.println("excel");
    }else {
        System.out.println("not found");

}
  }}
```

Comment: What language is this?  It looks like Java, but you should add an explicit tag.

Comment: I clearly need to figure out how to ask questions better so I can find the answer without creating a duplicate question. I'm still learning and will do better next time.Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
if (result.subSequence(2, 10).equals(result1)) {
    System.out.println("excel");
} else {
    System.out.println("not found");
}
```

The `==` symbol might be the one causing it to return false because of the different references.

This post should explain more about differences between `==` and `equals()`: [What is the difference between == vs equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-vs-equals-in-java)

Comment: This worked the way i needed. Thanks for a speedy answer. I'm self teaching java, so thanks for the web link.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say without more information (for example what language is this in).

Assuming this is Java, I would say your problem is using `==` with strings instead of the `.equals` function. 
`==` doesn't check the contents of the string, only if they are referencing the same object. `.equals` should be used instead as it actually checks whether the characters match in the two strings

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the `.equals` method should be preferred to the `==` operator when checking for semantic equality. `.equals` should be used when you are checking if two values "mean" the same thing, whereas `==` checks if they're the same exact object.